# Show validation errors in FancyBox in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, fancybox

I have a FancyBox in the home page which contains a registration form.

Validation is working fine.

Currently, I have to manually click on the FancyBox to see the error messages on that form.

Here's the code which reloads the page. But I want it to show the FancyBox as soon as the page loads. It is just a simple validation check.

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    $this->load->view('valform');
}
else
{
    $this->load->view('formsubmit');
}
```

So what I want is to show that FancyBox with validation errors.

Validation is working, as it is shown in the FancyBox; when the page reloads I have to manually click on that FancyBox to see the validation errors. Is there a way I can store it in a session and use that instead? If yes, how? Or how can I use ajax for this, and get validation errors to show on the FancyBox?

Comment: There are two means of "validation".  One is that you are getting validation errors in your code (maybe in your IDE?).  The other is that you are trying to validate the fancybox when the user submits the form, and trying to show the user what they did wrong, and it isn't working.  Please try to make your code a bit clearer.  Also, please update the question to show us both the code for the fancybox and the errors you are getting.

Comment: Validation is working , as it is shown in fancybox, when the page reloads I have to manually click on that fancybox to see validation errors. Is there a way I can store it in session and use that instead? If yes then how??

Comment: If you want to show your form validation error on fancybox, you might have to use Ajax and respond data as a json or html.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the example below. Try to implement it with ajax and jquery.

```
public function ajax_()
{
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('par','name of something','required');

  if($this->form_validation->run()!=TRUE)
  {
    echo json_encode(array('result'=>'error','msg'=>validation_errors()));
  }
  else
  {
    echo json_encode(array('result'=>'success','msg'=>'success'));
  }
}
```